# Variation of the Ricci Tensor

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, curvature, unitarity

In my own research into the use of Clifford Algebras with the Standard Model, gravity appears, but in calculating the Lagrangian of the theory I get:

$$-\frac{3}{4}\sqrt{-g}R^{\alpha\beta}R_{\alpha\beta}$$

for the gravitational contribution.  A term like this also appeared in Weyl's conformal extension.  This is clearly different than the Einstein-Hilbert action but what are the reasons why this wouldn't work?  I've read/heard mention of the quartic nature being an issue, but I'd love help in understanding the physics reasons why this kind of term is excluded from possibility.

Comment: Please explain exactly what step of the process is confusing to you. Also, make sure to add in details about what exactly you've attempted so far.

Comment: Start by computing the variation of the Christoffel symbols. Then move on to the variation of the Riemann and Ricci tensors.

Comment: It looks like you are varying the *square* of the Ricci tensor.

Comment: @Ghoster the [original version](https://physics.stackexchange.com/revisions/777739/1) was looking at terms like $(\delta R^{\mu\nu}/\delta g^{\alpha\beta})R_{\mu\nu}$

Comment: Concerning v2 of the question, the key phrase is "Ostrogradsky instabilities".  [This Q&A](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/610562/what-is-an-intuitive-way-of-understanding-ostrogradsky-instability) has a nice example of how this manifests in a toy example from Newtonian mechanics.

Answer (score 1):

Being a good physicist, you should first of all do an order of magnitude analysis.

Compared with the regular Einstein-Hilbert Lagrangian (where $G$ is the gravitational constant)
$$
\sim\frac{1}{G}\sqrt{-g}R
$$
your two-curvature Lagrangian

$$
\sim\sqrt{-g}R^{\alpha\beta}R_{\alpha\beta}
$$
is roughly of the order:
$$
O(\frac{R^{\alpha\beta}}{G^{-1}}) \sim O(\frac{E^2}{M_p^2})
$$
where $E$ is the typical energy scale of the physical system in concern, and $M_p$ is the Planck energy.

As you can see, unless the typical energy scale of the physical system $E$ is approaching Planck scale, your two-curvature Lagrangian is extremely small compared with the regular Einstein-Hilbert Lagrangian. **Therefore it's irrelevant at normal energy scales.**

Additionally, adding high-curvature terms nilly-willy could potentially induce tachyons, which is an unwelcome feature.